# AzureDirectory with Lucene.Net and an Azure Worker Role

Tags: lucene.net, azure-storage, azure-worker-roles

I am trying to implement a Lucene.Net index using AzureDirectory inside Azure blob storage.

The indexing process runs from an Azure worker role.

In the local azure emulator, I can process ~3million records into the index and it is very fast to search.

Now I am trying to get it up into live Azure, and the worker role starts processing fine.

The problem I have is that after ~500,000 records or so, the worker role falls over and restarts.

I have exception handling, and I'm using diagnostics with trace statements both throughout the code, in the exception handler and in the OnStop event. The trace statements from the main code appear in the diagnostics table fine, and gives me a log of my records getting processed, but the trace statements from the exception handling and the OnStop never show up.

There is a lot of code to post, so I thought I'd start by asking initially if anyone knew of any limitations around this type of Lucene.Net index with AzureDirectory?

**EDIT:**
I finally managed to get an exception by moving a little code around.
The index is running out of disk space and I get the below exception. Going to try and increase the space and will post back results.

> There is not enough space on the disk.   at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.FileStream.WriteCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   count)    at
>   Lucene.Net.Store.SimpleFSDirectory.SimpleFSIndexOutput.FlushBuffer(Byte[]
>   b, Int32 offset, Int32 size)    at
>   Lucene.Net.Store.BufferedIndexOutput.Flush()    at
>   Lucene.Net.Store.BufferedIndexOutput.WriteBytes(Byte[] b, Int32
>   offset, Int32 length)    at
>   Lucene.Net.Store.RAMOutputStream.WriteTo(IndexOutput out_Renamed)
>   at Lucene.Net.Index.StoredFieldsWriter.FinishDocument(PerDoc perDoc)
>   at Lucene.Net.Index.DocumentsWriter.WaitQueue.WriteDocument(DocWriter
>   doc)    at Lucene.Net.Index.DocumentsWriter.WaitQueue.Add(DocWriter
>   doc)    at
>   Lucene.Net.Index.DocumentsWriter.FinishDocument(DocumentsWriterThreadState
>   perThread, DocWriter docWriter)    at
>   Lucene.Net.Index.DocumentsWriter.UpdateDocument(Document doc, Analyzer
>   analyzer, Term delTerm)    at
>   Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.AddDocument(Document doc, Analyzer
>   analyzer)

**Final Update**
So I now have my indexer indexing 3.3million rows of data in approximately 5 minutes.

I have went back to RAM based storage and slightly reduced the data being indexed, there were 3 fields in my document, reduced to 2 now.

Searching the index from an azure webrole is lightning fast as well.

I have taken onboard everyone's comments on and will be monitoring this over the next month or so. I'll be interested to see how it performs under load.

Comment: Hah, so my suggestion on my blog was right after all :) Where are you storing the index? In the Azure Storage (BLOB)?

Comment: yep in a blob. By default AzureDirectory writes to disk, but on their codeplex site they say they use is using RAMDirectory, so trying that now. I have made this change and it is still running just now. I'll updated once it's done. It's slowing waaaaay down after ~2mill rows though, so may have to try committing more often. Update later today/tomorrow!  cheers Leon!

Comment: Alright, I look forward to your findings, interesting problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I posted this before...but...

Its not going work for production environments...Here is my answer on why its not and what you can do: [How to implement Lucene .Net search on Azure webrole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222479/how-to-implement-lucene-net-search-on-azure-webrole/13223048#13223048)

I should add running your own Azure VM has advantages since you can stripe disks for extra I/O performance (important during indexing and searching outside RAM).

Here is another answer that might help, but I don't agree with the approach: https://azuredirectory.codeplex.com/discussions/402913

Edit: I should clarify that when I say "work" I mean work in a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented my version of AzureDirectory [here](http://linqtolucene.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/96133#1753982)

Maybe it will help you, you will always eventually run out of RAM with RAMDirectory - it's just a question of the number of documents.

Comment: thanks Karell, I will check this out. Do you have any stats for your  statement about RAMDirectory?

Comment: Also, I was running out of disk space when using the default so that is why I moved to RAM

Comment: In either case you are dealing with limited resources. Azure VMs don't have unlimited disk or ram. In the case of just using local cache (which should flush if it gets full) you should be fine. However, be prepared to be hit with an initial startup cost when an instance comes up as it downloads the cache files for that first search. I usually add a small query on the instance startup event so that it immediately start downloading/creating the cache. Regretfully, I don't have numbers/stats for you - I have been meaning to do an analysis for quite some time.

Comment: Consider also looking into the Azure.Drive component of the same project which uses an Azure Drive - it's much less "patchy"