# Best practices and test cases for Lucene.Net Custom Directory Implementation

Tags: amazon-s3, lucene.net, azure-storage

I'm relatively new to Lucene.Net and still lack a good judgement as to what makes a reliable, production grade extensibility implementations, specifically for custom directory. Currently, I'm looking at implementing Azure and S3 custom directories. Although one might suggest taking an [existing AzureDirectory](http://azuredirectory.codeplex.com/) implementation, [it is suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222479/how-to-implement-lucene-net-search-on-azure-webrole/13223048#13223048) that it's not of production quality. In addition, it doesn't have any unit tests, so when Lucene or Azure Storage Library are updated, there is no reliable way to adjust and test API. I tried to discern a test suite from Lucene.Net code base, but it seems directory tests are scattered all over the test project and there is no simple way to do that.

That being said, could you advise on the following:

1. What are best practices for implementing custom directory?
2. What are essential test cases to ensure production quality of the
   implementation?
3. Any performance metrics that must be met in order for implementation
   to scale when index grows and number of search requests increases?

Comment: This is not an answer, but figured I would give you guidance...I spent a couple months digging into Lucene and Lucene.NET before choosing a path for production for my software (you linked to my comment).  You have some really good questions, frankly ones that scared me off of AzureDirectory.  Based on what you said about not being familiar with Lucene.NET, you have to choose do you want to deliver software or write complex Lucene internals.  I chose Lucene.NET over Solr, because I want full control and understanding of what is going on under the hood.  However, I also balanced that out..

Comment: ...by writing my own custom Analyzers, Filters, index implementation set up BUT NOT writing my own Directory implementation.  I am NOT a Lucene expert by any means, thus I wanted to deliver software that was high grade but not spend 4 months writing infrastructure code...that doesn't pay the bills.  Ultimately, I really liked the flexibility Azure gave me with the VHD data disks that can be attached to VMs/copied for backups/re-attached somewhere else.  I can move large number of indexes WITHOUT getting charged for transactions.  I can stripe VHD data disks (RAID) for extra I/O perf etc.

Comment: ...with an Azure Directory, I didn't know how nor I don't think I could achieve all those same things.

Comment: @Bart thank you for your insight, this looks like one of the options I might consider. Some clarifications as to my experience and goals: 1. I'm using Lucene.Net API in my application for about half a year now, so I already feel comfortable using it, however I don't have any experience writing extensibility code; 2. I need to be able to store index both in Azure and S3 and do it using the same approach. That's why I'm likely to prefer writing custom directories instead of using FSDirectory/VHD approach.

Comment: You might be able to find some base implementations in the Contrib sections of the Lucene/Lucene.NET source code.  Another thing I looked at was changing the RAMDirectory to DistributedRAMDirectory with high availability in cloud caches, you can pretty much store the indexes in RAM the entire time simplifies the Directory implementaton a bit.

Comment: @Bart That's a really interesting lead. I will look at RAMDirectory and will let you know about my findings. Thank you very much!

Comment: RedisDirectory could be a start: https://github.com/maxpert/RedisDirectory